# How can i give the same layout both in portrait and landscape mode with onConfigurationChange()?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

Welcome

I must force the app to work only in portrait mode, but i need to know when the user has moved the phone to landscape mode. Why? because i am displaying a opengl view with a texture image, and when the user changues the phone position to landscape mode i must rotate the polygon without reseting the activity. Then i must force portrait mode on manifest, because i dont want that my onCreate method gets called again.

I'm trying it with this aproach: android:configChanges="orientation" this stops recreating activity then override the onConfigurationChange() method. when orientation change occurs, that method wil be called then i will change the image as i want.

The problem is that when i'm changing the orientation of the phone, my layout is also changing, and i dont want that, i want to give the same layout both in portrait and landscape mode, and after i achieve that i will generate the rotation, and the rotation is not the problem, because i know how to do it.

How can i give the same layout both in portrait and landscape mode with onConfigurationChange()?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that these changing the orientation or distribution in which objects appear in your layout.

What you need is to add in the activity properties in file `AndroidManifest.xml`

**android:screenOrientation="portrait"**

With this no longer allows the user to rotate the screen while the rotate your phone.

Comment: but if i use android:screenOrientation="portrait" then the method onConfigurationChange() is never called.... and i need to know when the user has rotated the phone to make my opengl rotation :S

Answer (score 0):

you can create your landscape's layout as you want it to appear under

```
res/layout-land/my_layout.xml
```

Comment: you didn't understand my question

Answer (score 0):

Okie, If I am guessing right then you need to do two things. In this way once layout that has been set in OnCreate method doesn't change on orientation and one layout is sufficient for the same

1. Add one attribute in activity tag which you want to get orientated as below

   ```
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
   ```
2. Add below function in the activity without doing any change in this function do nothing in config changes

   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
               super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   }

Comment: please, read my question fully. I tryed that, and didn't works, when i'm changing the orientation of the phone, my layout is also changing, and i dont want that, i want to give the same layout both in portrait and landscape mode,

Comment: Do you want to use same xml layout file in both orientation?

Comment: no, i'm not using XML's, i'm using a GLSurfaceView, that it is a layout bytheway, i need to use the same without reorganicing my elements of the screen, please read the question carefully